# Default support for xinclude in Java 6?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan, xinclude

I see in my application that xinclude inside my parsed XML file does not work within my Java XSLT conversion.

However, although I do:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
```

I'm not specifically setting the transformer factory as `System.getProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory")` returns "null".

My question: does the default Java (1.6 or 6) support xinclude or do I have to add an alternative XSLT parser such as Apache Xerces?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://jaxp-sources.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/spec/html/), support has been there since Java 1.5 (5). I believe XInclude support relies on [namespace awareness](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)), which is turned off by default for backwards compatibility reasons.

```
public class XIncludeDemo {

    private static final String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
            + "<data xmlns=\"foo\" xmlns:xi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude\">\n"
            + "<xi:include href=\"include.txt\" parse=\"text\"/>\n"
            + "</data>\n";

    private static final String INCLUDE = "Hello, World!";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // data
        final InputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML
                .getBytes("UTF-8"));
        final InputStream includeStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(INCLUDE
                .getBytes("UTF-8"));
        // document parser
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        if (!docBuilder.isXIncludeAware()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        docBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
                if (systemId.endsWith("include.txt")) {
                    return new InputSource(includeStream);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlStream);
        // print result
        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will need some time to apply it and see if I can accept it. The information you gave me is however what I needed.