# java - xml generation from excel sheet content

Tags: java, xml, excel

I have a xsd and a MS-Excel spreadsheet. The excel sheet contains Xpath like representation of all the elements/fields of the xsd along with the corresponding data type as specified in the xsd.

For example if xsd contains a element as follows:

```
<xsd:complexType name="person">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The excel sheet content is as follows:

```
Column 2 (element/field name)        Column 3 (data type)
person.name                          String
person.age                           String
```

I have a requirement to check if the content of the excel sheet is valid and complete.
Thus I want to a generate xml file from a MS-Excel spreadsheet and validate it aganist an existing xsd.

The requirement details are as follows:

1. Read the content of the second and third column of a MS-Excel spreadsheet.
2. Ignore the rows whose content does not contain a dot separator
3. generate xml
4. validate it aganist the user specified xsd

How can this be done in a java program?

Answer (score 1):

There are several Java libraries to read Excel documents, including [jxl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxl/) and [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). (You might also consider using a CSV file (Comma Separated Values), which is simpler than Excel and not proprietary.)

To parse the XSD file, use Java's [built-in XML parser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = domBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("file.xsd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XInclude to insert the values into your document. There is an example of it here: [Default support for xinclude in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581939/default-support-for-xinclude-in-java-6)

You will need to write your own entity resolver, which can then read the Excel-file and find the right values there. I don't have any experience with jxl, but JExcel is a solid library for manipulating Excel-files.

Answer (score 0):

How about https://community.informatica.com/solutions/b2bdt_automation_template_excel_generator if you have Informatica DT installed? You can generate the script through java, and execute it on command line using java!