# XSLT and XInclude

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xinclude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default support for xinclude in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581939/default-support-for-xinclude-in-java-6)

I have a three XML files called `A.xml`,`B.xml` and `C.xml`.
A includes B and C through XInclude.

I want Saxon to process A.xml AFTER resolving the includes in A.xml.

So far, I can activate the XInclude but Saxon does not receive the resolved A.xml but the raw version :\

How can i do ?

Saxon 9.3 HE
Java 6